# can not validate form before submission

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

i have form , which is submitted using `$.ajax` function , but before submitting i am validating it using jquery validate() function. but when i click on submit button both functions runs simultaneously. so , how to validate form before submitting it.

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal" name="attr_val_form" id="attr_val_form" action="admin_operation.php?mode=add_attr_value&id=<?php echo @$row_data['attr_val_id']; ?>&attr_id=<?php echo $attr_id; ?>" method="post">
              <fieldset>
                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-lg-4 control-label " for="attr_val">Name</label>
                  <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <input id="attr_val" name="attr_val" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md"  type="text"  value="<?php echo @$row_data['attr_val']; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="attr_id" id="attr_id" value="<?php echo $attr_id; ?>">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-lg-4 control-label" for="sortorder">Sort Order</label>
                  <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <input id="sortorder" name="sortorder" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row_data['sortorder'];  ?>">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Button -->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-lg-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
                  <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="save">save</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </form>
          </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
//validation
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#attr_val_form").validate({

        errorElement:'div',
        rules: {
            attr_val: "required",
            sortorder: "required"
        },
        messages: {

            attr_val: "Required.",
            sortorder: "Required."
         }

       });
    });

//form submit

$('#attr_val_form').submit(function(event) {

    // get the form data
    // there are many ways to get this data using jQuery (you can use the class or id also)
    var formData = {
    'attr_val' : $('input[name=attr_val]').val(),
    'attr_id' : $('input[name=attr_id]').val(),
    'sortorder' : $('input[name=sortorder]').val(),

    };

        // process the form
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
            url : 'admin_operation.php?mode=add_attr_value', // the url where we want to POST
            data : formData, // our data object
            cache: false,

             success: function(data)
                   { 

                    if($.trim(data)== 'yes')
                    {  

                      $("#notice")
                       .show()
                       .html('<div class="alert alert-success"<strong>Successfully !</strong> record added.</div>')
                       .fadeOut(3000);


                     }
                    else
                    {
                       $("#notice")
                       .show()
                       .html('<div class="alert alert-danger"<strong>Error !</strong> Record already exist.</div>')
                       .fadeOut(3000);
                    }
                  }

            })
            // using the done promise callback


    // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
    event.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the validator's [submitHandler](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submitHandler) callback to submit the form

```
//validation
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#attr_val_form").validate({
        errorElement: 'div',
        rules: {
            attr_val: "required",
            sortorder: "required"
        },
        messages: {

            attr_val: "Required.",
            sortorder: "Required."
        },
        submitHandler: function () {

            // get the form data
            // there are many ways to get this data using jQuery (you can use the class or id also)
            var formData = {
                'attr_val': $('input[name=attr_val]').val(),
                    'attr_id': $('input[name=attr_id]').val(),
                    'sortorder': $('input[name=sortorder]').val(),

            };

            // process the form
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
                url: 'admin_operation.php?mode=add_attr_value', // the url where we want to POST
                data: formData, // our data object
                cache: false,

                success: function (data) {

                    if ($.trim(data) == 'yes') {

                        $("#notice")
                            .show()
                            .html('<div class="alert alert-success"<strong>Successfully !</strong> record added.</div>')
                            .fadeOut(3000);


                    } else {
                        $("#notice")
                            .show()
                            .html('<div class="alert alert-danger"<strong>Error !</strong> Record already exist.</div>')
                            .fadeOut(3000);
                    }
                }

            })
            // using the done promise callback

            //prevent the default form submit
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TdaU6/)

Comment: tnk u for help,and quick reply.

Comment: Arun, you should make sure the OP is properly tagged with [tag:jquery-validate] so that others browsing the jQuery Validate questions don't miss this.